# Return random row in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a testimonial table that I would like to display on my main page on my Laravel 4 project. Usual I would just run a query to get the random row:

```
SELECT * FROM `testimonials` WHERE `id`=".mt_rand(1,3);
```

But I get this error when trying to run it:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '".mt_rand(1,3)' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT * FROM `testimonials` WHERE `id`=".mt_rand(1,3);) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, ))
```

Here is my Controller:

```
        public function showHome()
{
            DB::select('SELECT * FROM `testimonials` WHERE `id`=".mt_rand(1,3);', array(1));
    return View::make('home.index', array('pageTitle' => 'Home'));
}
```

Another side question is how do I display this information in my home.blade.php template?

I would usual do a while loop and do something like $row['assoc_array']

Answer (score 1):

```
$testimonial = DB::table('testimonials')->where('id', mt_rand(1, 3))->first();
return View::make('home.index', array('pageTitle' => 'Home', 'testimonial' => $testimonial));
```

This should provide a variable called "testimonial" you can use in your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showHome()
{
    DB::select('SELECT * FROM `testimonials` WHERE `id`=' . mt_rand(1, 3));
    return View::make('home.index', array('pageTitle' => 'Home'));
}
```

Comment: ok I didnt get any errors so that seems to be good. So, what about part two of my question. How do I use blade to loop through them and output them?

Comment: Post another question for a different question

Comment: seriously? It has to do with my main question. The row is not randomly returned. The DB part of it may work but not the output.